# Need help to figure out how to update a key.value in some list of python dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hi guys I have this data:

```
members = [{'n1': 1, 'active': True, 'ticket': 10, },
             {'n2': 2, 'active': False, 'ticket': 0, },
             {'n3': 3, 'active': True, 'ticket': 12, }]
```

I need to update the members time to time, to check if they are active or not, and give new tickets to active members and maybe filtering the inactive ones.

For checking actives or inactive I can use some like this:

```
inactive = list(filter(lambda n: n.get('active') == False, members))
```

Or maybe keep the inactive but not give them new tickets.
The updates are user inputs for n and tickets.
So i need to check if the inputs are already in the dict just to update the data needed, ie. If users input 1 for n I just have 1 already so I just update ticket. Else i update both.

But I got a lil stucked in how could I check if the the number I will input in n is already in the dict inside the list.

For new members I can use some like this:

```
updated = {'n': int(input('number'), 'active': True, 'ticket': int(input('number')}
```

So in summary:
I need to check if n.value is in the dict, if so update only the ['ticket].value or if not update the dict with n and ticket new values.

Paulo

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow right. You have some number, for example `3` and you want to know if item with key `n3` is in the list `members`?

Comment: I edited the text, I holp now it  gets clear.

Comment: Why are you using different `n` keys? Why not use the same key for each item?  Putting information in keys is a bad idea and leads to problems like this. The whole data structure should probably be a dictionary keyed to the member id.

Comment: Consider another data structure that allows easier access to its attributes, e.g. a data class, named tuple...

Comment: I am not rying to change or update the keys of the dict, just apenas the values of the keys what is a commom task in python. But I cant find the code to checkif the value is in the key or not and if there Ijust update ticket value, if not I update the two values instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> members = [{'n': 1, 'active': True, 'ticket': 10, },
...             {'n': 2, 'active': False, 'ticket': 0, },
...             {'n': 3, 'active': True, 'ticket': 12, }]
```

To find a member, you just have to iterate over the members until you find the good one:

```
>>> def find_member(k):
...    return next(((i, m) for i, m in enumerate(members)  if m['n'] == k), (-1, None))
```

The `next` function will return the first found member whose key `'n'` has the value `k`, or `Npne` if there is none.
I added an index if you need to remove a member by name.

```
>>> find_member(2)
(1, {'n': 2, 'active': False, 'ticket': 0})
>>> find_member(10)
(-1, None)
```

To update a member, use this function and do the update:

```
>>> def update_member(k, t):
...     i, m = find_member(k)
...     if i == -1:
...         members.append({'n': k, 'active': True, 'ticket': t})
...     else:
...         m.update({'ticket': t})

>>> update_member(1, 15)
>>> members
[{'n': 1, 'active': True, 'ticket': 15}, {'n': 2, 'active': False, 'ticket': 0}, {'n': 3, 'active': True, 'ticket': 12}]
```

My advice is: create a class `Member` that wraps the dict and provides some useful methods (`set_active`, `renew_ticket`, ...) and a class `Members` that wraps the list and provides other useful methods (`find_by_name`, `update_by_name`, `delete_by_name`, ...)